# unzipping a file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

which one is better to unzip a file in C# using window shell or uzipping it in c# using third party software like DotNetZip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DotNetZip has worked very well for me in WinForms apps.

The built in Windows Zip functionality seems quite picky about files and fails easy.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use a library, it will (should) be faster, and easier to test and debug. I've used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) in the past with no problems.